GitHub Actions Not Resolving GitHub Packages via Sbt Plugin
I have a project where I build a sbt settings plugin that I intend to use across all my other projects. In this sbt plugin project, I define several common settings like resolvers, scm info, other static settings.
I then publish this setting to my organizations package in GitHub and I can even see it being available as shown here: https://github.com/orgs/open-electrons/packages
I then use this sbt settings plugin in my other projects by adding it like this in the plugins.sbt project like this:
addSbtPlugin("com.openelectrons" % "openelectrons-sbt-settings" % "0.0.1")

When I run this project (say Project A) which has this build.sbt:
import SharedSettings._

lazy val commonSettings = SharedSettings.settings

// Build definition for the ocpp-gateway-server project
lazy val ocppGatewayServer = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, DockerPlugin)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    ....
    ....

The SharedSettings come from the sbt settings plugin that is available in the GitHub packages. I then include all those settings in this project like above. The SharedSettings actually contain the resolvers defined like this:
  // Dependency resolvers
  val sharedResolvers: Seq[Resolver] = Seq(
    Resolver.mavenCentral,
    "Typesafe Releases" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    "Typesafe Snapshots" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/",
    "GitHub Packages" at "https://maven.pkg.github.com/open-electrons/open-electrons-templates"
  ) ++ Resolver.sonatypeOssRepos("snapshots") ++ Resolver.sonatypeOssRepos("releases")

When I run my Project A, I cannot see that the GitHub Packages is even resolved. The build looks for the openelectrons-sbt-settings dependency in repo1 and in these 3 locations:
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/openelectrons/openelectrons-sbt-settings_2.12_1.0/0.0.1/openelectrons-sbt-settings-0.0.1.pom
[error]   not found: /home/runner/.ivy2/localcom.openelectrons/openelectrons-sbt-settings/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.openelectrons/openelectrons-sbt-settings/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.openelectrons/openelectrons-sbt-settings/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml

I do not see any log lines where it tried to download it from GitHub Packages. How do I fix this?

If I understand correctly, the main project has to add GitHub in the resolvers. It cannot use the resolvers from the plugin if the plugin cannot be downloaded because it's not available in the usual repositories. Or, an alternative is to set the repositories to use in the /etc/sbt/repositories file.

Other way around. I have a project called sbt-settings-plugin which gets built as an sbt plugin. In this plugin, I set all the common settings that I want to reuse for all projects in my organization. I publish this plugin to my GitHub package. In my project A where I use this plugin, I would expect that the plugin itself is downloaded from the Github Packages and this is where the problem is as GitHub as a package is not getting resolved

That's what I meant: how can project A knows it has to use GitHub repository to download the plugin?

I believe that for the plugin to be found, the resolvers need to be overridden in the plugins.sbt file itself (this is probably what was mentioned in a comment: if you put the resolver for the plugin in the plugin itself, you are creating a bootstrapping problem).
Try this:
resolvers += "GitHub Packages" at "https://maven.pkg.github.com/open-electrons/open-electrons-templates"

addSbtPlugin("com.openelectrons" % "openelectrons-sbt-settings" % "0.0.1")


After doing this, atleast the resolver is now looking for the dependencies. I now face authentication problem even after setting and exposing the environments. but this is the solution and it works.
